# Force subclasses of an interface to implement ToString

Tags: c#, oop

Say I have an interface `IFoo` and I want all subclasses of `IFoo` to override Object's `ToString` method. Is this possible?

Simply adding the method signature to IFoo as such doesn't work:

```
interface IFoo
{
    String ToString();
}
```

since all the subclasses extend `Object` and provide an implementation that way, so the compiler doesn't complain about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239408/can-i-force-subclasses-to-override-a-method-without-making-it-abstract <--? same? or just very similar?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it with an interface. You can use an abstract base class though:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract override string ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: I was hoping stick with interfaces since I've already gotten them written, guess I'll have to bite the bullet and switch abstract classes. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer (and I think the only reasonable possibility) but it has a drawback in C#'s lack of support for multiple inheritance. Any class that must inherit from Base cannot inherit from any other non-Base class i.e. class MyClass : ThirdPartyClass, Base // mot possible

Comment: Jon, is the answer by @SebT below now more correct or are there pitfalls? It suggests IFormattable.

Comment: @AppFzx: Well that doesn't for any implementation of `IFoo` to override the parameterless `ToString` method. See https://gist.github.com/jskeet/f9fed44a4395105cd63e3f71e9785d58 for example. So I'd say it doesn't really satisfy the requirements of the question.

Answer (score 21):

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public override abstract string ToString();
}

class Bar : Foo
{
    // need to override ToString()
}
```

Comment: Question was "can I do this with an interface?", not "how do I do this?", but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry to bury out this old thread from the grave, specially as our dear @jon-skeet [already provided his own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510358/734181).

But if you want to keep the interface and not use an abstract class, I guess this is still possible by simply having your interface implementing the [System.IFormattable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

```
interface IFoo : IFormattable
{
}
```

The only thing to keep in mind is, to properly implement this IFormattable, the concrete implementation should overwrite the `Object.ToString()` as well.

[This is clearly explained in this nice post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268961/734181)

Your concrete class is now like

```
public class Bar : IFoo
{
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return $"{nameof(Bar)}";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(null, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

Hope this might still help anyone.

Answer (score 9):

Jon & Andrew: That abstract trick is really useful; I had no idea you could end the chain by declaring it as abstract.  Cheers :)

In the past when I've required that ToString() be overriden in derived classes, I've always used a pattern like the following:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract string ToStringImpl();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToStringImpl();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementing an interface method implicitly seals the method (as well as overriding it). So, unless you tell it otherwise, the first implementation of an interface ends the override chain in C#.

[Essential .NET](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/0201734117/qid=1120928552/sr=8-1/ref=pd_bbs_ur_1?v=glance&s=books&n=507846)

Abstract class = your friend

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239408/can-i-force-subclasses-to-override-a-method-without-making-it-abstract)

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but since there is no way to do what you're asking for, I thought I'd share my own approach for others to see.

I use a hybrid of Mark and Andrew's proposed solutions.

In my application, all domain-entities derive from an abstract base-class:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this is IHasDescription
                   ? ((IHasDescription) this).EntityDescription
                   : base.ToString();
    }
}
```

The interface itself only defines a simple accessor:

```
public interface IHasDescription : IEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a description (in english) of the Entity.
    /// </summary>
    string EntityDescription { get; }
}
```

So now there's a fall-back mechanism built in - or in other words, an `Entity` that implements `IHasDescription` must provide the `EntityDescription`, but any `Entity` can still convert to a string.

I know this isn't radically different from the other solutions proposed here, but I like the idea of minimizing the responsibility of the base `Entity` type, so that implementing the description-interface remains optional, but you're forced to actually implement the description-method if you're implementing the interface.

IMHO, interfaces that are implemented by the `object` base-class should not "count" as implemented - it would be nice to have a compiler option for that, but, oh well...

Comment: You could use `as` instead of `is` to avoid a second cast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can force any sub-class to *override* any of the base-class's virtual methods unless those methods are abstract.