# Is there a way to make derived classes override ToString()?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface, tostring

(I'm working in .NET 4.0 beta, C#.)

I have an interface, and all classes derived from this interface should implement custom `ToString()` logic. Is that enforceable? If so, how?

Comment: If you _need_ a class to override `ToString()`, then you're implying a stronger contract for `ToString()` than what is generally used. If so, it may be that defining a separate method, rather than reusing `ToString()` for your purpose, is a better choice.

Comment: It's possible. My situation is that I want people to know "if you call `ToString()` on any class of type `IMyInterface`, you'll get something having to do with the unique type of data that every `IMyInterface` should contain, and not just the usual implementation which gives you something like the name of the class IIRC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510341/force-subclasses-of-an-interface-to-implement-tostring

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not through an interface.

You'll need to use an abstract class for this.

-- Edit

You can just re-declare 'ToString' as abstract:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public override abstract string ToString ();
}
```