# Reference Implementation for IFormattable

Tags: c#, .net, iformattable

Is there a good reference implementation for [IFormattable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx)?  I plan to have at least one custom `IFormatProvider` for my object, and I want to make sure that the wiring is correct for the different possible parameter sets passed to `IFormattable.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)`.

What I have so far:

```
public class MyDataClass : IFormattable
{
    /// <seealso cref="IFormattable.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)"/>
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        ICustomFormatter formatter = (ICustomFormatter)formatProvider.GetFormat(typeof(ICustomFormatter));
        return formatter.Format(format, this, formatProvider);
    }
}
```

But it seems like there are other potential situations that should be covered, i.e.:

1. If `formatProvider` is null, should I fall back to `this.ToString()`?
2. If `formatProvider.GetFormat(typeof(ICustomFormatter))` returns `null`, is there a particular exception I should throw?

Any blog posts / code samples / MSDN references are appreciated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the design of the .NET Framework's formatting infrastructure. `ICustomFormatter` should never be referenced inside an implementation of `IFormattable.ToString`, since that clashes with the intended purpose of that interface.

## `IFormattable`

An object should only implement `IFormattable` if it knows how to format itself (ideally it should delegate that to another class of course, but there would be deliberate coupling here). An object may know how to format itself multiple different ways, so the format string allows you to pick between them. Even with that there may still be missing information, such things that vary by culture. Therefore there is a second parameter that provides such information indirectly.

The type passed to `IFormatProvider.GetFormat` is intended to be a type or interface specific to the class the `IFormatProvider` was provided to.

For example, the built-in numeric types want to be able to retrieve an instance of `System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo`, while the `DateTime` related classes want to be able to retrieve a `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo`.

### Implementing `IFormattable`

So let's imagine we are creating some new self-formatting class. If it knows only one way to format itself, it should simply override `object.ToString()`, and nothing more. If the class knows more than one way to format itself should implement `IFormattable`.

#### The `format` parameter

Per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring.aspx) of `IFormattable.ToString` the format string of `"G"` (which represents the general format) **must** be supported. It is recommended that a null or empty format string be equivalent to a format string of `"G"`. The exact meaning is otherwise up to us.

#### The `formatProvider` parameter

If we need anything culture specific, or that would otherwise vary we need to utilize the `IFormatProvider` parameter. There would be some type that we request from it using `IFormatProvider.GetFormat`. If the `IFormatProvider` is null, or if `IFormatProvider.GetFormat` returns null for the type we want we should fall back to some default source for this varying information.

The default source need not be static. It is conceivable that the default source might be a user setting in the app, and the `formatProvider` is used to preview option changes and/or when a fixed format is needed for serialization.

It is also possible that formatting may involve formatting some sub-object. In that case you probably want to pass the `IFormatProvider` down. MSDN has an [excellent example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx#IFormattable) of implementing `IFormattable` that shows this very case.

### Other `ToString` overloads

When implementing `IFormattable` it is important that `Object.ToString()` be overridden in a manner equivalent to the following

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.ToString(null, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Doing so ensures that `somestring + yourobject` is equivalent to `string.Format("{0}{1}",somestring, yourobject)`, which your users will expect to be true.

For the convenience of your users, you should probably provide `string ToString(string format)`.  Also if your default format has any varying components that can benefit from the `IFormatProvider`, you may also want to provide `public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)`.

## `ICustomFormatter`

So what do we do if we want to format a class that does not know how to format itself, or we want to use some format not supported by the class itself.  That is where ICustomFormatter becomes relevant. An `IFormatProvider` that can provide the `ICustomFormatter` type can be passed as the `IFormatProvider` parameter in methods like `string.Format` and `StringBuilder.AppendFormat`.

The provided `ICustomFormatter` has its `Format` method called for each formatting that `string.Format` does. If the `ICustomFormatter` is unfamiliar with the format string used or has no support for that type it simply delegates to `IFormattable.ToString` or `Object.ToString`. The [`ICustomFormatter` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx) provides a list of what is needed if you are formatting an object that does not already provide formatting support, and what is needed if you merely want to add an extra format to an existing `IFormattable`. It also provides an example of the adding an extra format case.

## Reference

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx) provides a great overview of the .NET formatting system, and provides links to pretty much all the other relevant pages in MSDN. It is the best place to start for almost any formatting related question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and references!

Comment: When I first read this question I was basically as confused about all of this as you were, so I Looked at the framework in reflector, and started reading MSDN pages, and I only got more confused. It took ontil I had read the majority of the MSDN pages before I found that main reference page. Even then, It took a while before it started to click. There are some tricky parts. For example, I suspect the only reason `ICustomFormatter` is used with IFormatProvider is because it was a late addition to the 1.0 framework, and they did not want to add a new `string.Format` overload.

Answer (score 1):

For such questions a good *source* of information can be found inside [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) source code. You'll likely find quite a few uses of this inside its [mscorlib.dll](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/corlib) code.