# C# Method Override & Inherit Base Functionality

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I'm still relatively new to C# so sorry if this is a dumb question. I am trying to make a multi-program application that will allow users to edit data from a database. Each application should have some common functionallity when the edit method is called (e.g. Toggle the application into edit mode). Is there any way that I can make subclasses of BaseClass run BaseClass.Edit() before running the contents of the overridden Edit() method?

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void Edit(){
        // Some common functionality goes here
    }    
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public void Edit(){
        // Do BaseClass.Edit() first...
        // Some more application specific functionality goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `SubClass` is *obscuring* or *hiding* the `BaseClass` method.  This generates a compiler warning because it's almost always not what was intended.

Make the `BaseClass` method `virtual`:

```
public virtual void Edit(){
    // Some common functionality goes here
}
```

And explicitly override it in the `SubClass`:

```
public override void Edit(){
    // Do BaseClass.Edit() first...
    // Some more application specific functionality goes here
}
```

Then you can explicitly invoke the `BaseClass` method first:

```
public override void Edit(){
    base.Edit();
    // Some more application specific functionality goes here
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can use this and also force the subclass to create an overridden version of the BaseClass method? (Like what would happen if BaseClass.Edit() was marked as abstract)

Comment: @BloodySolomon: Not that I'm immediately aware of.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2118055/328193) looks like a good place to learn more about that.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have shown how to call `Edit()` in the base class. But, depending on your needs, here's another pattern that might work.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Edit()
    {
        // Common functionality here
        OnEdit();
    }

    protected virtual void OnEdit() {}
    

}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void OnEdit()
    {
        // Specialized functionality here
    }
}
```

Here, the `Edit()` function only exists in `BaseClass`. But you can add subsequent functionality by overriding `OnEdit()`.

This is an advantage if `Edit()` must always be implemented. It works even if you don't add custom functionality (override `OnEdit()`). But you can override it as needed.

And if you want to require that `OnEdit()` is *always* overridden, just make it `abstract` instead of `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Edit(){
        // Some common functionality goes here
    }    
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Edit(){
        base.Edit();
    }
}
```